# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Caption Fails to Render

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I have found lots of questions here having the same problem as mine. However, those do not solve my problem. I have exactly the same code as this

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

However, the following div just never render in my django template. What am I possibly missing? The image carousel is rendering properly, so my .js, .css files shall be loaded correctly.

```
<div class="carousel-caption">
```

Answer (score 0):

I somehow figured out to render it now. If you have an image, then after the image is rendered, the caption will be automatically rendering. Before that, caption has no height!